# Google maps API: Why can't I set the icon of my markers by using relative icon paths?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, icons, relative-path

These are my marker options

```
var markerOptions = {
                clickable: true,
                draggable: false,
                flat: true,
                map: map,
                icon: 'food.png',
                optimized: true,
                position: pos,
                title: name,
                visible: true,
                animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            };
```

`'food.png'` is in the same folder of the javascript file. However it doesn't work.

If I use the full http path it works fine. For example

```
http://localhost/javascript/food.png
```

is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: Does it work on a publicly available website (not localhost?). Does it work with optimized:false?

Comment: [This example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple) from the documentation works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon image needs to be in the same directory as the HTML page it is being referenced from, not the same directory as the javascript.

Update: as webaware pointed out a relative path to the icon should be relative to the directory containing the HTML document.

The [example from the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple) works fine both on the Google site and locally on my machine.

Comment: More specifically, the path to the icon is relative to the HTML document, not the script file.